# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, jsonp

I really new to ajax and jsonp and having a problem reading from a file when called. The code works. But every time I call the same function again in the same script it says 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'. If the function works once shouldn't it always work?

**Here is a sample of my code**

```
var resultAmount = 0;

start = function(teamFile, rowsInDB, ratio_Over_rows, opplastx_gp, callfunction){

    //ajax ONLY calls don't return anything
    (function($) {
    //Connects to the json teamFile
    var url = 'http://xxx.co.uk/football/'+teamFile+'.json?callback=?';
    //Automatic refresh

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {

        if(callfunction == 'mep'){

            resultCount(data, rWin, count);
            resultCount(data, rDraw, count);
            resultCount(data, rLose, count);

            //the total of w/d/l
            resultAmount =  total[rWin] + total[rDraw] + total[rLose] ;

        }else{}

    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
})(jQuery);

}


//Adds the results w, d, l up
 resultCount = function(for_data, result, count_r){

    count_r = 0;

    //Goes through the data
    for(k in for_data){
        //if equals w, d, 1
        if(for_data[k].Results == result){
            //Add 1
            count_r++;
        }else{

        } 
    }
  }

//Then I call the function start twice only one works
console.log(start('ast', 7,5,5, 'mep'));
console.log(start('ars', 7,5,5, 'mep'));
```

Only the first function runs and not the second it says 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'. And when I change them around the first function runs and the second says 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'.

If it helps my file looks like this

```
jsonCallback([{"Brad Guzan":"yes","Jed Steer":"no","Ashley Westwood":"yes","Fabian Delph":"no","Ron Vlaar":"yes","Andreas Weimann":"yes","Gabriel Agbonlahor":"no","Nathan Baker":"yes","Leandro Bacuna":"yes","Karim El Ahmadi":"no","Christian Benteke":"no","Ciaran Clark":"no","Matthew Lowton":"yes","Ryan Bertrand":"yes","Antonio Luna":"no","Marc Albrighton":"yes","Libor Koz\u00e1k":"no","Aleksandar Tonev":"no","Yacouba Sylla":"no","Grant Holt":"yes","Joseph Bennett":"yes","Chris Herd":"no","Jordan Bowery":"no","Jores Okore":"no","Gary Gardner":"no","Daniel Johnson":"no","Nicklas Helenius":"no","Jack Grealish":"no","Janoi Donacien":"no","Callum Robinson":"no","last_gp":"lose","2nd_gp":"lose","3rd_gp":"win","4th_gp":"lose","5th_gp":"lose","Home":"home","Results":"lose"});
```

Comment: You mean the error is on the line `console.log(start('ars', 7,5,5, 'mep'));`? Or is there more to the stacktrace?

Comment: Is that all your code? Because if it is, your second function is not complete and will not compile. Thus it won't run.

Comment: You're also missing a closing array bracket in your returned data.

Comment: Yes it is the console.log(start('ars', 7,5,5, 'mep')); the full code has the closing bracket, it just a lot of code and I had to shorten it for an example of what is happening

Comment: Search all your code, make sure you don't have `start = ` somewhere else, as that would redefine your function definition.

Comment: Done that only called 3 times, One for the function twice for the call the function

Comment: I think it has something to do with the url changing??? what do you think?

Comment: Repsoduce the issue on http://jsbin.com/ , update the question with the link to jsbin, then report back here.

Comment: funny enough it work on jsbin reading the data but not printing out the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out was that both of the files had 'jsonCallback' as a function on the document being read. Each jsonCallback or function should be unique. What was happening before was a conflict and now it is unique.

Examle:

```
function handleData( responseData ) {
    // do what you want with the data
    console.log(responseData);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "hi.php",
    ...
    success: function ( data, status, XHR ) {
        handleData(data);
    }
});
```